# k8s core_v1_api list_pod_for_all_namespaces failed with exception: urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength

Tags: python, kubernetes, urllib3

I am using kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api (https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/client/api/core_v1_api.py)

Sometimes code failed on:

```
for pod_event in self._watcher.stream(func=self._core_api.list_pod_for_all_namespaces, **watch_kwargs):
```

getting this exception:

```
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))
```

I have some suggestion:

- I think to adding timeout_seconds=0 while watch.stream loop
  https://medium.com/programming-kubernetes/building-stuff-with-the-kubernetes-api-part-3-using-python-aea5ab16f627
  I am not sure if it will help
- try to catch this specific exception and ignore it. because it mean trying to chunk empty string (I am not sure if its mean there is no more data)
- upgrade urlib3/kubernetes packages on my project or open issue for this